# How to separate values from 1 column?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, database-administration

I am having a table name **tbl_details** where it gives output as column name **Memo No., Client Name, Stoneid, Status** along with values given below. I tried many solutions from SF but none worked for me, so i posted here.

[image]

Question:
I want to find number of **Stoneid is Pending, Completed and Returned** and **if Total No. of Stones column is equal to No. Of Stones Completed then Final Status will be Completed**. I am sharing the 4 Scenerios in below images

[image]

I am new to this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @TheImpaler , I want the pivot table. I am not able to form query, I am very new.  1st image is table value, 2 one is the output I want from table, simple. thanks for you quick response.

Comment: Here you go: `select
  memo_no, 
  client_name,
  count(*) as total_stones,
  sum(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end) as completed,
  sum(case when status = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) as pending,
  sum(case when status = 'Return' then 1 else 0 end) as returned,
  case when sum(case when status = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
       then 'Completed' 
       else 'Pending' 
  end as final_status
from tbl_details
group by memo_no, client_name`

Comment: @TheImpaler, Thank you very much, it was so easy. I highly appreciate your quick response.